# Tabs com slideUp() e slideDown() para left e right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou usando um *plugin* de `tab.js` e para mudar de *tab* ele usa `slideUp()` e `slideDown()`.

Só que eu gostaria de usar `Left` e `Right`. Como fazer?

Meu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
(function ($) { 
    $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
    $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
        var tab = $(this).closest('.tab'), 
            index = $(this).closest('li').index();  
            tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
            tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
            tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();
        g.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Link para o código usado: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/MightyShaban/pen/zLykK)

Answer (score 1):

Aqui fica um exemplo de slide horizontal. Devo dizer que o slideUp() e slideDown() não permitem fazer o mesmo efeito na horizontal.

Isto é um exemplo que eu fiz, a semelhança com o seu código é usar-se o index do menu para ir buscar a div que se quer ver.
Note também o HTML que tem um wrapper para os slides/tabs.

Não tive tempo de adaptar o seu código, mas se não compreender posso fazer isso amanhã.

```
$('#menu div').on('click', function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var largura = $('#wrapper').width();
    var aberta = $('#wrapper div.aberta');
    var clicada = $('#wrapper div').eq(index);

    if (clicada.hasClass('aberta')) return false;

    aberta.animate({
        'left': -largura
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('aberta').hide();
    });

    clicada.css('left', '300px').show().animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, 200).addClass('aberta');

});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/szLtQ/)